# Work with excel in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I need to do some school project, it's a kind of wage calculator.

I need load excel file as a "database" (first only to fill the combobox).

In second sub in "do until" cycle I'm getting some exception error ("An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MzdovySystem.exe but was not handled in user code").

I'm a beginner, so I don't know, how to solve this. I can't get, that in the first sub it's ok, but in second not. Also, I'm using almost the same code in another form and it works fine. Can anybody help me please?

Public Class Form1

```
Dim xlPath
Dim xlFile
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    xlPath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath
    xlPath = xlPath.Replace("MzdovySystem\bin\Debug", "")
    xlFile = xlPath + "db.xlsx"

    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlFile)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("zam")

    Try

        Dim radky As Integer = 1

        Do Until IsNothing(xlWorkSheet.Range("A" & radky).Value) = True
            radky = radky + 1
        Loop

        radky = radky - 1

        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 2 To radky
            combo1.Items.Add(xlWorkSheet.Range("A" & i).Value)
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception : MsgBox("Chyba při načítání databáze zaměstnanců")

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub combo1_TabIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles combo1.TabIndexChanged

   Dim radky As Integer = 1

    Do Until IsNothing(xlWorkSheet.Range("A" & radky).Value) = True
        radky = radky + 1
    Loop
```

Public Class Form2

```
Dim xlPath
Dim xlFile
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    xlPath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath
    xlPath = xlPath.Replace("MzdovySystem\bin\Debug", "")
    xlFile = xlPath + "db.xlsx"

    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlFile)
    xlWorksheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("nastaveni")

    With xlWorksheet

        PracovniDoba.Text = .Cells(1, 2).value
        ZamcSoc.Text = .Cells(2, 2).value
        ZamcZdr.Text = .Cells(3, 2).value
        ZamlSoc.Text = .Cells(4, 2).value
        ZamlZdr.Text = .Cells(5, 2).value
        HodnotaStr.Text = .Cells(6, 2).value

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub PracovniDoba_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PracovniDoba.TextChanged

    For Each znak In PracovniDoba.Text()
        If Asc(znak) > 47 And Asc(znak) > 58 Then
            PracovniDoba.Text = "8"
            MsgBox("Do tohoto pole je možné zadat pouze čílo")
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ZamcSoc_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ZamcSoc.TextChanged

    For Each znak In ZamcSoc.Text
        If Asc(znak) > 47 And Asc(znak) > 58 Then
            ZamcSoc.Text = "0,045"
            MsgBox("Do tohoto pole je možné zadat pouze čílo")
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ZamcZdr_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ZamcZdr.TextChanged

    For Each znak In ZamcZdr.Text()
        If Asc(znak) > 47 And Asc(znak) > 58 Then
            ZamcZdr.Text = "0,65"
            MsgBox("Do tohoto pole je možné zadat pouze čílo")
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ZamlSoc_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ZamlSoc.TextChanged

    For Each znak In ZamlSoc.Text()
        If Asc(znak) > 47 And Asc(znak) > 58 Then
            ZamlSoc.Text = "0,25"
            MsgBox("Do tohoto pole je možné zadat pouze čílo")
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ZamlZdr_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ZamlZdr.TextChanged

    For Each znak In ZamlZdr.Text()
        If Asc(znak) > 47 And Asc(znak) > 58 Then
            ZamlZdr.Text = "0,09"
            MsgBox("Do tohoto pole je možné zadat pouze čílo")
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub HodnotaStr_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HodnotaStr.TextChanged

    For Each znak In HodnotaStr.Text()
        If Asc(znak) > 47 And Asc(znak) > 58 Then
            HodnotaStr.Text = "60"
            MsgBox("Do tohoto pole je možné zadat pouze čílo")
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ulozit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ulozit.Click

    With xlWorksheet

        .Cells(1, 2).value = PracovniDoba.Text
        .Cells(2, 2).value = ZamcSoc.Text
        .Cells(3, 2).value = ZamcZdr.Text
        .Cells(4, 2).value = ZamlSoc.Text
        .Cells(5, 2).value = ZamlZdr.Text
        .Cells(6, 2).value = HodnotaStr.Text

    End With

    xlWorkBook.Save()

    MsgBox("Nastavní bylo úspěšně změněno.")

End Sub

Private Sub zavrit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles zavrit.Click

    Me.Close()
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    ReleaseComObject(xlApp)
    ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook)
    ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet)

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Are you disposing "xlWorkSheet" or setting it to null (Nothing) in anywhere else?

Comment: I'm using it in one more form, everything works fine there... I have one main form, it's a menu with 3 buttons (1st form, 2nd form and close), in 2nd form it works ok, but in 1st not. I've adden 2nd form code above. All things in Form2 wokrs well, but error pops up when I want open Form1 from menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are using TabIndexChanged event and this event appears to be fired before Form's load event, before xlWorkSheet is set.

Probably you should use combo's SelectedIndexChange event, because if you do not change tab orders in your code TabIndexChanged event fired only once for your form or you check if xlWorkSheet is set to something.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm totally blind, I've choosen bad event and tryig with it all the time.